# How I can write this equality in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

[image]

hi every one can you help me resolving this              ;s

Comment: *This* equality? There are a number of them in the screen shot. Could you be a bit more specific? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 8):

Another *equality* from this screenshot is

```
$k=1$.
```

(can be seen at the end of page 7)

As this is the top most equality completely visible, the question is surely about this one :)

Comment: @HenriMenke I already have a bad conscience as this makes fun of the question, I would not want to get any rep points for this.

Answer (score 3):

I have considered just this below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\text{bla, bla} ~~~k!\sum^k_{i=0}(-1)^{k-i}\binom{k}{i}i^n=\sum^k_{i=0}\frac{(-1)^{k-i}}{i!(k-i)!}i^{n}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly. You could also use `\qquad` or `\hspace{2cm}` for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the requested equations:

```
\begin{equation}
x^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} S_{k}^{n} x^{\underbar k}
\end{equation}
```

The result can be seen between "Et on sait  que[...]" and the comma.